# jquery: stop function immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouseover

when mouseover `.down`, the div layer slides down
when mouseover `.up`, the div layer slides up

If the mouse goes over `.b`, how do I get the div to slide down without having to wait for the div layer to slide up first? basically kill the previous function **immediately**

```
<a href="#" class="down">Slide Down</a>
<a href="#" class="up">Slide Up</a>

<div style="height:400px;width:200px;background-color:#ccc">
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.down').mouseover(function() {
        $('div').slideDown();                          
    });

    $('.up').mouseover(function() {
        $('div').slideUp();                        
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `.stop()` function?

Comment: link: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: @Pointy, @jbail, thanks, looking into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Adding an answer so the question is not left "unanswered".*

Per @Pointy, the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop) function is what you want. You would add it before you call `.slideDown()` in order to stop the element's currently-running animation.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.down').mouseover(function() { 
        $('div').stop(true, true).slideDown();                           
    }); 

    $('.up').mouseover(function() { 
        $('div').slideUp();                         
    }); 
});
```